# Access - If statement to choose values from other tables

Tags: ms-access, if-statement

I have three tables, each with 10 columns and the same number of rows. One table(the "indicator" table) has either a 1 or a 2 in each cell. The other two tables (lets call them Tables 1 and 2) have numerical data in them.

What I want to do is to make a new table with 10 columns and the same number of rows as the other tables. For each "cell," if the indicator table has a 1 for that cell, pull the numerical value for that cell from Table 1, and pull from Table 2 if the indicator value is 2.

This would be easy in Excel. If I had three tabs with 10 columns and some # of rows, it would be something like =if(Indicator!B1=1, Table1!B1, Table2!B1), copied across the whole range. However, I need to do this in Access and for some reason I just can't wrap my head around it, since I'm a heavy Excel user who is new to Access.

Any ideas? I'm sure there is an easy way to do this, I just can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The position of the rows is consistent between tables. Row m, column n in the Indicator table indicates whether to select row m, column n from Table 1 or row m, column n from Table 2. It's translating this to Access that I'm having a hard time with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to join the two tables and then use an iif statement for this.
In order to work, you will need a join predicate to match the corresponding lines.

So you would end with

- Table Indicator (id, col1,..,col10)
- Table DataA (indicatorId, col1,..,col10)
- Table DataB (indicatorId, col1,..,col10)

now you can select:

```
SELECT i.id,
    iif(i.col1=1, a.col1,b.col1) as col1,
    ...,
    iif(i.col10=1, a.col10,b.col10) as col10
FROM (Indicator AS i
INNER JOIN DataA AS a ON (i.id=a.indicatorId))
INNER JOIN DataB AS b ON (i.id=b.indicatorId))
ORDER BY i.id
```

Please note that this syntax is Access-Specific and won't port to other SQL engines, e.g. MSSQL will need WHEN...THEN...ELSE...END instead of iif.

Also note that such queries will have quite a bad performance because of the conditionals in the select-part.

Comment: I used a variation of this and it worked well. I should note that the join predicates I used were columns and not rows, so the row terminology is misleading for my scenario. I was also a little tripped up on the table aliases, which I'd never seen before. Anyway, this answer worked for me. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @synapticfits: thanks for the feedback, I updated the answer to better match the question.